# Show scroll to right arrow when horizontal scrollbar is present in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On my site I have tables adapt to the size of the screen and use a horizontal scrollbar like this.

[image]

What I want is to show an arrow element within the table when there is more info to the right and clicking the arrow scrolls to it over to the right.

Something that looks like this.

[image]

Click the arrow and the table is scrolled over all the way to the right.

[image]

How do I display the arrow element only within the table and only when there's a horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the widths [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of your table and the scrolling container. If the container width is smaller than the table, you can use show the arrow, else have it hidden.